# How do e-commerce websites integrate with ERP systems?

Tags: python, e-commerce, netsuite, sap-erp

How does e-commerce usually handle integrations with ERP software?
We are working on a project for a client, who previously planned to use an ERP system that had a REST API.

This API allowed us to:

- Place orders
- Inform the ERP if the order was paid for
- Get order status
- Get all of the items available
- Check item availability
- Get user data

That would allow us to build a fairly complex online store with a lot of features.

Now the client wants to use another ERP system:
http://www.netsuite.com/portal/platform.shtml

I researched it, and the difficulty of integration surprised me. No REST API, some weird SOAP protocol to communicate with the system, and you have to write a lot of logic using SuiteScript. A whole new, different programming language just to build an integration with an online store? Why not just give developers access to an API to place orders and fetch items? And there are absolutely no docs available online for the thing. People on forums are saying that the system lacks in documentation and one has figure it out himself, along the way.
Magento and Shopify integration is done by third parties and looks dodgy. Same thing with SAP ERP. Am I missing something? Why is such a basic thing as a REST API for e-commerce not available for those systems?

Why develop using Python Django for the back-end and using React.js for the frontend. What is the right way to integrate them with the ERP system?

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite does have a REST API and webservices. "you have to write a lot of logic using SuiteScript" is true but it's just JavaScript and there are many talented developers out there.
I'm not sure there is a "right way" but there are many ways to connect to the data.

My suggestion would be to contact a partner company, such as SWK Technologies. http://swktech.com

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite has two main APIs, SuiteTalk and SuiteScript.

SuiteTalk is the Web Services API, which is SOAP based and allows for pulling data from and updating NetSuite. The SuiteScript API is JavaScript based and allows you to customize accounts and export data at the appropriate event during your business process. The term "SuiteCloud" encompasses all APIs and integration tools.

As for documentation, this is mostly only available to clients and partners. If you have a client who provides you with access to their account, you will gain access to the NetSuite Help Center and all relevant documentation.

Your options for integrating with the e-commerce platform depends on the exact platform. This ranges from Webhooks to HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say NetSuite is delimiting developers in any way. It depends on how you look at it. As I see it, NetSuite provides two main method for developers - SuiteTalk and SuiteScript.By this, developer can create his/her own API, define what kind of acces those API should have.

SuiteTalk is SOAP based.

I would suggest using SuiteScript to create your own API using either NS RESTlet or NS Suitelet. 
They have the feature for External URL. By sending request to this external URL you can trigger your own custom functions written on the SuiteScript. By SuiteScript, you can create your own API and define your own function. Ie, developer is in full control.

The only problem I see with NetSuite is its higher barrier for entry. There is no way you can access NetSuite Help Centre without having a Client/Partner/Test account.

But obviously, those who need some kind of integration with NetSuite have NS account.